# Can anyone help me to clear my understanding of TCP/IP System calls?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

1. `listen(5)`: Here, Does it mean that server can be connected to only 5 clients?
2. `select()`: As per wiki select system call is used when we continuously wants to monitor the port for input/output,then if we don't use `select()` then also we can monitor that particular port right?
3. While accepting the connection we have to use `select()` system call, why can't we use simple array to save the newsfd?

for ex: (using Python)

```
SocketFd = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
SocketFD.bind((ip, port))
SocketFd.listen(5)
i = 0
NewSFD = []
while True:
     NewSFD[i] = SocketFd.accept()
     i += 1
     if i == 5:
         break
```

Comment: Your last question needs some clarification I think. One one hand you say "why can't we use simple array to save the newsfd?" but your sample code does this; so what's the "why" part of the question here?

Comment: @JamesMills Sample code is not working, so my question is why can't we do like that?

Comment: A comment about the below answers: for TCP sockets, there are two competing families of syscalls to do actual I/O. For other kinds of sockets (e.g. UDP), you must use `send`/`recv`; for non-sockets, you must use `read`/`write`. Each of these named syscalls has a whole family of similar functions (e.g. `sendto`, `recvmmsg`, `pread`, `writev`)

Comment: @ChiragGangdev What are you expecting your code to do and what isn't working about it? (*I don't think it'll do what you expect*).

Comment: @JamesMills: in my code i want that server should wait till 5 clients connect to it, so evrytime i use accept() it will return a newsfd, right? so i am storing newsfd into an array, so that i can use it for send/recv msgs for each clients

Comment: @ChiragGangdev This *might* work; but it's a rather naive approach to "waiting for 5 clients to connect". Then what? You *should* probably look into an Asynchronous I/O library/framework such as [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio.html)

Comment: @JamesMills No, this code is not working.. So only i am asking why its not working? it should work right? and yes if i include select() system call above accept, then it is working,
Ex:
While True:
    inputready, outputready, exceptready = select.select(ListOfSocketFD, [], [])
    for x in inputready:
        if X==SocketFD:
     NewSocketFD, HostAddr=SocketFD.accept()

Comment: @ChiragGangdev See: https://gist.github.com/874416e6f0a64d358d98 (*your sample had quite a few errors*). **Note:** This program terminates after 5 clients have connected so it's not terribly very useful :)

Comment: @JamesMills: Ok. Thanks for your valuable time :)

Answer (score 3):

1. The argument to [`listen`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/listen) is the *backlog* of connections - that is, the number of connections that can be queued by the kernel that you *haven't* accepted (because your program can't respond instantly). Set it to 1 if you only have one client, otherwise pass `SOMAXCONN`.
2. There are three ways to implement a server: servers that only have one client at a time (and are thus boring, though you do still have to worry about which direction you're sending traffic), servers that allocate one thread per client (which can be costly and requires synchronization) and use blocking calls, and servers that use a single thread and use nonblocking calls (though it is sometimes possible to do load-balancing between multiple threads with this technique). I am only focusing on the third kind here.

In order to use nonblocking sockets, you must set the `O_NONBLOCK` flag (which allows `read` and `write` to return `EAGAIN` (in `errno`)), then pass all of the sockets to one of the multiplexing syscalls. Originally there was [`select`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select), but [`poll`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) is a much better alternative and is also standard. Nonstandard alternatives include [`epoll`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/epoll_create) on Linux and [`kqueue`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/kqueue/) on *BSD (including Mac OS X).

Your chosen multiplexing syscall will let your program sleep until there is activity on one of the sockets you are interested in. Otherwise, you would have to burn 100% CPU trying every file descriptor in turn even though most of them are going to be `EAGAIN` at any given moment, but wasting CPU is an unforgivable sin. In my (admittedly anecdotal) experience, a server will usually use about 10% CPU with a typical number of clients (the limiting factor is usually the bandwidth of the client). But it is absolutely essential that your server uses 0% CPU when no client is connected (unless it also has tasks that must be executed on a timer even when no client is watching).

Note that the multiplexing syscalls take a timeout, which should be set to how long until the next timer is scheduled (timers are usually stored in a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) and the earliest timer is the root). If you don't have any timers scheduled, there is a special value that indicates "forever".

3. I'm not sure what you're asking, you don't have to use `select` in order to `accept`. However, if you pass the listening socket to `select` (this is required to have more than one client in the nonblocking model), it will appear as readable when `accept` might return a new client (though spurious notifications are **always** possible).

Answer (score 2):

1. The actual TCP connection (3-way handshake) is established by the system *before* your code calls `accept()`. The `listen` call is a hint to indicate to the system how many TCP connections it is allowed to establish before being `accept`ed by the application code.  I typically set this value much higher than 5.
2. You can call `recv` with the `MSG_DONTWAIT` and `MSG_PEEK` flags to poll a socket without blocking.  Another option is to use `setsockopt` with `SO_RCVTIMEO` flag.
3. Your question here is confusing. The answer ross gave in his answer is probably in line with what I would say.

Answer (score 2):

This *answers* your last implied question.

This is a *correct* version of your sample code that listens for incoming connections and terminates after it has accepted 5 connections. (*This program is not really that useful!*).

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket

ip, port = "0.0.0.0", 10000

SocketFd = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
SocketFd.bind((ip, port))
SocketFd.listen(5)

NewSFD = []
while True:
    NewSFD.append(SocketFd.accept())
    if len(NewSFD) == 5:
        break
```

Your sample code has numerous errors:

- Missing `socket` import
- Misnamed variable(s)
- Assigning arbitrary values to an empty list instead of appending

Answer (score 1):

1. See [the Linux man page on listen](http://linux.die.net/man/2/listen). The backlog parameter limits the number of pending connections in the socket's listen queue.
2. See [The GNU C Library: Waiting for I/O](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Waiting-for-I_002fO.html). While the `read` function could be used for the same purposes, `select` is a much more efficient method of retrieving input from multiple sources.
3. The `select` function blocks the calling process until there is activity on any of the specified sets of file descriptors, or until the timeout period has expired. So, the short answer is that `select` is a convenience that allows us to forego an inefficient polling scheme.

Comment: I think 1) could be elaborated on a bit; specifically what the listening queue means in practice. 2) is a bit confusing as read() and select() do really different things; read() is blocking whilst select() is non-blocking.